# Create CSV file within Python using 'for' or 'if' conditions

Tags: python, csv, for-loop, if-statement

I have designed code as:

```
import csv
import numpy as np
data = [['Diameter', 'color', 'no']]
with open('samp1.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in data:
        writer.writerow(row)
    for i in np.arange(20,30,0.2):
        writer.writerow(i)

f.close()
```

And I want to save numbers from 20-30 with an increment of 0.2 in the *diameter* column, but it's giving errors and not even saving the CSV file. Can someone suggest any solution? Even there are various ranges for other columns too, so I need the same method to work for that code.

CSV example

```
diameter    color     number
20          2         3
20          2.5       3
20          3         3
20          3.5       3
20.2        2         3
20.2        2.5       3
20.2        3         3
20.2        3.5       3
.
.
.
.
22          2         4
22          2.5       4
22          3         4
22          3.5       4
22.2        2         4
22.2        2.5       4
22.2        3         4
22.2        3.5       4
```

Comment: "its giving errors" => provide full error & traceback

Comment: its just sample code from my program where I have lots of columns and for each column I need to save different kind of data like in first column numbers from 20-30 but with difference of .2 and in another column 2-5 with difference .5 each particular number needed to be matched with new one..

Comment: can you add a sample o/p you are expecting ?

Comment: @Vikas Damodar I have added sample o/p so can you guide me please. Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this can help you:

```
import csv

data = ['Diameter', 'color', 'no']
numb = [i for i in range(20,30,2)]
print(numb)
with open('samp1.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(data)
    for i in numb:
            writer.writerow([i,i,i])

f.close()
```

Comment: Thankyou @RamG its working for me.And can I know if we want to save this range data in particular column is it possible?

Comment: Happy to hear problem solved , please mark this as answer , yup u can do it , declare new array for them and put them instead of  "i" in 
            for i in numb:
               writer.writerow([i,i,i])

Answer (score 1):

What about using pandas library for creating it? Using it you can freely choose which part of DataFrame you want to save to csv.

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df.to_csv('out.csv')
```

Comment: thankyou very much @Jakub but this will just display col1:[1,2] and col2:[3,4] I want to save data as col1: [range(20-30) increment by .2] and each number to be matched by another new value from col2:[range(2-5) increment by .5] can you guide me for this.